# facebook offline_access

Tags: facebook

ma web application uses the offline_access. As it will be deprecated by the first of may I am wondring how to manage the validity of the access_token. 
In the documentation https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/offline-access-removal/ they say (If the access_token is generated from a server-side OAuth call, the resulting access_token will have the longer expiration time) ! 
What is this "the longer expiration time?" and how I know that my token is not valid anymore?

Any one can help me? 
Thanx !

Answer (score 3):

From the page that you linked to in your question, the longer expiration time is 60 days:

> To get the access_token simply pass your own client_id (your app_id),
>   your app_secret, and the client-side access_token to the endpoint
>   below. The returned access_token will be set to expire in **60 days**. If
>   you would like to renew a still valid access_token, you will have to
>   get a new client-side access token first and then call the same
>   endpoint below. The returned access_token with the newly extended
>   expiration time may or may not be the same as the previously granted
>   extended access_token.

And [here is how to handle expired access tokens](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/500/).

Comment: I need to know how to handle the expiration time wihtout asking the user to login again? For example if my user had an access token the 30 april. The first of May he will be able to use my application without relogin?

And any body knows what happens if I check the "Deprecate offline access" before the first of may?

Thanx

Comment: As long as a user uses your app before the token expires, you will be able to renew/exchange the token.  A token can only be renewed once per day.  If a user is away from your app for over 60 days, the user will need to re-login to your app.

Comment: thanx for you answer. Actually I store the access_token in the database and as i used to use the offline_access I'h never checked for the validity of the token. So should I store the expire date in the date base? and redirect my user once the token is not valid any more....?

Comment: whenever the user uses your app, you should exchange the access token for a new one that will always expire in 60 days.  once you obtain the new token, store the new token in your database.  if you wait to to this until after the token is expired, the user will need to log in again.

Answer (score 0):

It's nice of Facebook to remove this.  Really messes up a lot of our work!  Now do you think that having a small windows/unix service running that could call the new end point say every 30 days with the right values would "solve" this.  It's not looking like the user has to be physically on your site as the end point is:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?             
    client_id=APP_ID&
    client_secret=APP_SECRET&
    grant_type=fb_exchange_token&
    fb_exchange_token=EXISTING_ACCESS_TOKEN
```

as you are just calling a URL and parsing the details?  So when someone connects to your app, get the new extended access token, save this to your db along with the expires date and with a the right setup up, call the URL every 30 days (or even 59 days if you want to play on the edge...) and up date it without the user ever needing to be physically on your site.  Seems like too easy away to get around the security...?

Comment: I would not recommend this.  Doing this would be a breach of Facebook's ToS. The OAuth specification definitively calls for short lived access tokens, and creating a service to indefinitely refresh these violates this.